# How to get random row from the last 5 row?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

**EDITED**: From the oldest 5 posts, I want to get one row from those in random.

---

How can I get a random row from the oldest 5 row?

I tried these below:

```
Post::oldest(5)->random()->first();
```

But return me an error:

> Call to undefined method Illumi
>   nate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::random()

Someone knows how to do it in simple and neatest way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Builder` class doesn't have a `random()` method, but a `Collection` does. Also, `oldest()` doesn't take an integer as it's argument, it's looking for a `column` to use (uses `created_at` as a default).

Use the following query instead:

```
$posts = Post::inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get();
```

Note: Don't use `->first()` if you want multiple rows; `->first()` returns the first row from the database, `->get()` returns rows in a `Collection`.

Edit: Misread the question. See the query below:

```
$randomPost = Post::oldest()->limit(5)->get()->random();
```

Use the initial `Post::oldest()->limit(5)->get()` to get 5 `Posts` ordered by `created_at`, then use `Collection` logic to return a single entry via `random()`.

Comment: Just curious, What happens if you use `->inRandomOrder()` after `->limit(5)`?

Comment: `limit(5)->inRandomOrder()` should be the same as `inRandomOrder()->limit(5)`; for most `Builder` instances (result of `Post::function()`) order of definition doesn't matter, as it is translated to the correct order of operations based on the database being used

Comment: @TimLewis I tried `Post::oldest()->limit(5)->get()->random()->first();` but it just return the same row. I tried it 10 times. And..

Comment: @TimLewis `Post::inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get();` I'm asking for a random row from the oldest 5 posts. Hmm.. I already updated my question.

Comment: Code has been updated (thanks @Remul) `$randomPost = Post::oldest()->limit(5)->get()->random();` should work, but I made an error; adding `->first()` to the query overrides `random()` and returns the first of the oldest.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim Lewis said, don't use `first` but instead, you can write `take` + the number of items you want to display

```php
return Post::inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get()->take(1);
//or
return Post::oldest()->take(5)->get()->random();
```

The `take` method returns a new collection with the specified number of items:
in this case, we took only one item, more info visit the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-take)
Hope it helps

Comment: I already knew `take()` but idk how to use it properly. Hmm you forgot, it must be from the oldest 5 posts.  thanks for reply

Comment: return Post::oldest()->take(5)->get()->random(1);
Try this

Comment: While this is correct, it should be noted that `take()` is an alias for `limit()`, and `random(1)` doesn't need a parameter if you only want a single entry. That means this answer is almost entirely a duplicate of mine, which is fine, but try to add something new to answers.

Comment: @TimLewis ahhh I'm about to question you that difference of `limit` and `take`. now ik thanks again Sir.

Comment: @gecko Haha read you mind :) Yeah, there's a number of functions on the `Builder` class that are aliases for other functions, that mostly exist to match `Collection` methods. (`Collection` doesn't have a `limit()` function, but does have `take()`, so `Builder` has both to handle common use cases)

Comment: @TimLewis thousand apology :) for my ignorance. Still newbie, currently watching jeffrey way's tutorial. thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @gecko No apologies necessary; we all start out somewhere. Keep at it!